# in mydata expected amount of records not coming

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have one datatable I should get 10 records, but its showing only 5 records (sl no 5-10). I'm using a dropdown list. There are 2 lists in my dropdown list. While selecting another item in the dropdown its again showing 5 records. I want to show 'entries 10'. Even though there are 100 records it's not showing 10 entries. While clicking 25 entries its showing '(6 - 25) 20 records'. There is some issue in for each loop in the table body

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">          
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h5>
                    Select Water Tank:
                    <select id="ddlPir">
                        <option value="28" selected="selected">K</option>
                       <option value="f2">
                            O
                        </option>
                      </select>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div style="overflow:scroll;overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <table id="listing" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">

                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
                            {
                                <tr class="tr_@item.value.deviceid">
                                    <td>@(item.i + 1)</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.UpdatedTime</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.filled</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.SensorData</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.battery</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.deviceid</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</div>

 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#listing tbody tr").hide();
                $("#listing tbody tr.tr_" + $("#ddlPir").val()).show();
                $('#ddlPir').change(function () {
                    $("#listing tbody tr").hide();
                    $("#listing tbody tr.tr_" + $(this).val()).show();
                });
            });
    </script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#listing').DataTable();
            });
    </script>
```

```csharp
// Model
public class WaterTankViewModel
{
  public double filled { get; set; }
  public double SensorData { get; set; }
  public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
  public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
  public string deviceid { get; set; }
  public double battery { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public ActionResult Details()
{
  List<WaterTankViewModel> model = new List<WaterTankViewModel>();
  model.AddRange(getWaterTankDetails("28", 28.5));
  model.AddRange(getWaterTankDetails("f2", 18));

  model = model.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime)).ToList();
  return View(model);
}


     private List<WaterTankViewModel> getWaterTankDetails(string deviceID, double height)
        {

            List<WaterTankViewModel> model = new List<WaterTankViewModel>();
                                      WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "a2Vybm==";
                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
                using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                    var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    List<WaterTankDetails> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WaterTankDetails>>(responseString);
                    foreach (var item in Pirs)
                    {
 dynamic wt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
                        string deviceid = deviceID;
                        WaterTankViewModel TankDetailsModel = new WaterTankViewModel();
                        TankDetailsModel.deviceid = deviceID;

                            string hexdata = BitConverter.ToString(data);
                            string enc = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace(@"-", string.Empty)

                            string battery = Convert.ToString(enc.Substring(6, 2));

                            TankDetailsModel.TankName = "xyz";
                            TankDetailsModel.deviceid = deviceID;
                            TankDetailsModel.battery = batteryLevel;
                            model.Add(TankDetailsModel);
                       }
                }

             return model;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I can't see the logic for responding to the `IndexChanged` event of your `dropdownlist`, nor can I see the actual result from your `getWaterTankDetails()` calls, so I doubt we'll be able to see why you're getting incorrect row counts.  I'd suggest break-pointing your data access code first...  Don't blame the view straight away!

Comment: i have  added dropdown indexchanged code in my question. and im getting 528 records in the model by combing both the device records. both have more than records.

Comment: How many records are you getting back for **each** of the calls to `getWaterTankDetails`?

Comment: In other words what is `Pirs.Count()` for **each** of the calls?

Comment: Pirs.Count= 212 for first device and , Pirs.Count=316 for second item